# python startswith function returns content of entire text file

Tags: python, startswith

I'm trying to extract all instances of the number that follows the string `PAX:`. The string that indicates PAX is preceded by a string that starts with `RCT`.

In the data below, I would be trying to extract `2`.

Data originally as follows:

```
"                                 T44-39                                 "
"RCT# 26798                                                       PAX: 2"
"STORE# 6                    TERMINAL# 3                         ONLINE"
```

Code of first attempt was as follows:

```
with open("e-journal.txt","r") as rf:
    with open("e-journal_py output.txt","w") as wf:
        for line in rf:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('"RCT#'):
                pax = line.split()
                pax2 = pax[3]
                print (pax2)
```

However, each line started and ended with `"`, so I attempted to replace `"` by revising the code.

After using the `replace` function, print returns the following:

```
T44-39                                 \nRCT# 26798                                                       PAX: 2\nSTORE# 6                    TERMINAL# 3                         ONLINE\n
```

Second attempt at code is as follows:

```
with open("e-journal.txt","r") as rf:
    with open("e-journal_py output.txt","w") as wf:
        data = rf.read()
        data = data.replace('"','')
        with open(data) as data:
            for line in data:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith("RCT"):
                    pax = line.split()
                    pax2 = pax[1]
```

The revised code removes `"` at the beginning and end of each line, but also returns content of the *entire* text file.  In other words, the `startswith` function does not return the number of `PAX`. How do I revise the code to return the number that follows the string `PAX`?

Also, given there is no code to print, I'm not sure what prompted the cost to return the entire data set

Comment: `startswith` returns `True/False`, not any part of the involved strings. Also, `with open(data) as data:` makes no sense at all, as `data` is the text content, not the name of a file.

Comment: Is the `\n` really in the data (as in "the two characters 'backslash' and 'n'), or is that supposed to be a newline? In the second case, it's better to show the file contents as-is, in a multi-line block.

Comment: You could try `with io.StringIO(data) as data`  instead of `with open(data) as data:`. It allows to process a string as is it was a file.

Comment: thanks all... used all your feedback from revising the open(data).. using the IO library... and learning how to use multi-line block's..  both my codes are working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt was the most sensible. It already returned `2"`, so all you had to do was to remove the trailing `"`.

You can use the `rstrip` string method to do that. Simply change

```
pax2 = pax[3]
```

to

```
pax2 = pax[3].rstrip('"')
```

or if you want to treat it as an integer, instead of a string, add `int()` around it:

```
pax2 = int(pax[3].rstrip('"'))
```